# Showing loading animation in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

How can I insert a div into another div using jquery? I'm trying to replace contents of my div with a loading div until the ajax call returns.

```
<div id="content1>foo</div>
<div id="content2>bar</div>
<div id="loadingDiv" class="loading-indicator"></div>
```

I have a common ajax requester that takes a div id and request url, which populates the div contents when the request is complete -

```
        MyCommon.GetAjaxCall(fetchUrl, data)
        .done(function (responseData) {
            // On success, put content
            $(responseContainer).html(responseData.View);
        })
```

Ideally, I just want to populate the contents of the responseContainer when I enter my function call to show the loading animation in the div and replace it with the response contents when the ajax completes.

I tried adding `$(responseContainer).html($("#loadingDiv").show());` (+some variations) and also tried appendChild to precede the GetAjaxCall above but none of those worked. I'm trying to have a dashboard style page layout with the data being populated in each div independent of each other and still show the same loading animation. Am I thinking about this the right way?

Comment: It seems like what you are trying should work. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9RDFV/) that works.

Comment: My loading div has no content in it, which is the part that is tripping me up. My spinner is similar to the tutorial here - http://www.codicode.com/art/pure_css3_loading_spinner_animations.aspx

Comment: I updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9RDFV/1/) with that style spinner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
   $('#content1').append($('#loadingDiv'));
```

If you want to do it via .html then make sure you do

```
 $('#content1').html($('#loadingDiv').html())
```